# Клиент-Сервер на разных машинах

Tags: c++, сеть

Не могу найти информацию нигде, как на c++ написать сервер и клиент так, чтобы расположив их на разных машинах, они все равно передавали информацию. Что надо исправить в следующем коде?

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <time.h> 

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int listenfd = 0, connfd = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr; 

    char sendBuff[1025];
    time_t ticks; 

    listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));
    memset(sendBuff, '0', sizeof(sendBuff)); 

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(5000); 

    bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)); 

    listen(listenfd, 10); 

    while(1)
    {
        connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)NULL, NULL); 

        ticks = time(NULL);
        snprintf(sendBuff, sizeof(sendBuff), "%.24s\r\n", ctime(&ticks));
        write(connfd, sendBuff, strlen(sendBuff)); 

        close(connfd);
        sleep(1);
    }
}

#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h> 

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd = 0, n = 0;
    char recvBuff[1024];
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr; 

    if(argc != 2)
    {
        printf("\n Usage: %s <ip of server> \n",argv[0]);
        return 1;
    } 

    memset(recvBuff, '0',sizeof(recvBuff));
    if((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
        printf("\n Error : Could not create socket \n");
        return 1;
    } 

    memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr)); 

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(5000); 

    if(inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[1], &serv_addr.sin_addr)<=0)
    {
        printf("\n inet_pton error occured\n");
        return 1;
    } 

    if( connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
    {
        printf("\n Error : Connect Failed \n");
        return 1;
    } 

    while ( (n = read(sockfd, recvBuff, sizeof(recvBuff)-1)) > 0)
    {
        recvBuff[n] = 0;
        if(fputs(recvBuff, stdout) == EOF)
        {
            printf("\n Error : Fputs error\n");
        }
    } 

    if(n < 0)
    {
        printf("\n Read error \n");
    } 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Компы, допустим, в разных городах.

Comment: Посмотрите здесь http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/, в частности главу 6.

Comment: Обратите внимание на аналогичный вопрос: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/34291/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос конечно не полный и требует правки, но я попробую догадаться о сути проблемы и ответить.

Сервер вы запускаете на одном компьютере и он начинает слушать соединения на сетевой порт конкретно этого компьютера. 
Клиент вы запускаете в каком-то другом городе и пытаетесь ввести адрес компьютера на котором запущен сервер.
Самая распространенная проблема, это попытка соединится с "сервером" который находится за роутером или, еще хуже, Айпи сервера "серый".

Если кратко, то Айпи адрес к которому стучится клиент должен быть именно тот которым владеет сервер. Часто этот IP адрес локальный и выдан wi-fi роутером, а роутер не настроен для передачи нужных запросов на нужный компьютер. Это легко исправить следуя инструкции роутера.

Второй момент гораздо хуже. Ваш провайдер выдал вам "серый" айпи и фактически вы сидите за "роутером", который у провайдера и именно это IP роутера показывают сервисы типа МойIP и конечно никакой клиент по этому адресу не находит ваш "сервер". Исправить это можно купив у провайдера дополнительную услугу "Белый IP" или "Статичный IP". Разница в том, что белый IP может динамически меняться, а статичный это строго привязанный к вам адрес, который не будет изменять провайдер в дальнейшем.

Надеюсь мой ответ был достаточно подробным. Ваш ответ слишком пространный. Надеюсь я угадал его скрытый смысл.

Comment: Спасибо, я просто пока что не очень хорошо разобрался в сетевых технологиях.

Comment: @GeorgeKasparyants Пожалуйста. Всегда рад помочь чем могу.