# Как заставить сокеты в python работать вне LAN

Tags: python, сокет

Я написал мессенджер с кодом подключения у сервера:

```
 def run(self):
        portOffset  = 0
        currentUid  = 0

        while(True):
            # Ожидание и принятие подключения
            listenChannel = socket.socket()
            listenChannel.bind(('', self.initport + portOffset))
            listenChannel.listen()
            collected = 0

            while(collected < self.capacity):
                channel, address = listenChannel.accept()
                collected += 1
                self.empty = False
                print(f"Подключено: {address[0]} ({collected}/{self.capacity}), ожидание получения метаданных")

                metadata = receivePackage(channel)
                print(f'Метаданные получены ({metadata})')

                # Отправка uid и данных других челов  клиенту
                sendPackage(channel, json.dumps([currentUid, {key:self.clientsData[key][1][META_USERNAME] for key in self.clientsData}]))
                print("Пакет init_data отправлен")
                print(json.dumps([currentUid, {int(key):self.clientsData[key][1][META_USERNAME] for key in self.clientsData}]))

                self.clientsData[currentUid] = [channel, json.loads(metadata)]
                self.newConnectedClients.append(currentUid)
                currentUid  += 1

            print("Сервер заполнен")
            listenChannel.close()
```

И для клиента:

```
def tryToConnect(address, port, username):
    if not port.isdigit():
        return 'Неправильный порт'

    # Подключение к серверу
    channel = socket.socket()
    try:
        channel.connect((address, int(port)))
        if DBGPRINT:
            print(f"Подключено")
    except ConnectionRefusedError as cre:
        channel.close()
        return f'Подключение провалено ({cre})'

    # Отправка метаданных
    if DBGPRINT:
        print("Отправление метаданных...")
    sendPackage(channel, json.dumps([username]))

    # Получение id и имён пользователей
    init_data = json.loads(receivePackage(channel))
    if DBGPRINT:
        print(f'initdata: {init_data}')
        print(f"Уникальный ID получен ({init_data[0]})")
    return (int(init_data[0]), channel, {int(key):init_data[1][key] for key in init_data[1]})
```

Всё работает отлично на 127.0.0.1. Но когда друг дал свой ip, который взял с 2ip.ru и запустил сервер, я не смог подключиться (Connection Refused Error). Когда мы попробовали подключаться через LogMeIn Hamachi (то есть через локальную сеть), всё работало. Почему так происходит? Сокеты ограничены только LAN? Или в коде подключений ошибка?

Comment: [Что такое NAT, или как нажить проблем за 5 минут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/613648/Клиент-Сервер-на-разных-машинах/613728#613728 Вот тут простым языком :)

Comment: спасибо за помощь, @ВладимирКлыков! жалко только что у меня проводное подключение и платить за белый IP не хочется :D